# How to create DataTable filled by JSON when number of columns is unknown

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table in my web-application, which is created like this:

```
<table id="mygrid">
    <thead>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
    </thead>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.oTable = $("#mygrid").dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bSort": false,
            "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("MyFunction", "Events")",
            "fnServerParams": function(aoData) {
                aoData.push({ name: "arg1", value: "@Model.arg1" });
            },
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "Column1" },
                { "mDataProp": "Column2" },
                { "mDataProp": "Column3" }
            ],
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bProcessing": false
        });
```

I fill it with function that returns JSON result, like this:

```
ActionResult MyFunction(string arg1, ...)
{
    List<string> someList = ...;
    object array = eventsList.Select(str => new
    {
        Column1 = str + "1",
        Column2 = str + "2",
        Column3 = str + "3"
    });

    var result = new
    {
        sEcho = ...,
        iTotalRecords = ...,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = ...,
        aaData = array
    };

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now I want to generate table dynamically, so I don't know the number of columns in design time. For example:

```
<table id="mygrid"><thead>
    @{
        foreach (string col in colNames)
            <th>@col</th>
    }
</thead></table>
```

Could you please advise how should I change my Javascript and C# code to fill the table in similar way? Is it possible? I can generate `"mDataProp"` lines in Javascript code like I generate columns, but how can I create JSON result in C# code?

**Added:**

I have solved the problem with controller. As I discovered, the List of Dictionaries is serialized to exactly the same JSON as the list of anonymous objects, so I wrote this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    list.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>());
    foreach (int colName in colNames) events[i][colName] = cellValue;
}
var result = new 
{
    ...,
    aaData = list
};
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Now I have new question. I cannot generate "aoColumns" array using C# loop like I generated  tags in HTML code. I tried like this:

```
"aoColumns": [
    @{
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            string colName = "Column" + i.ToString();
            { "mDataProp": "@colName" },
        }
    }
],
```

but it does not work. How can I do it?

Comment: so your have json string contains the rows of your data but you don't know how many columns for each row, am i correct??

Comment: I mean identifiers in following lines: Column1 = str + "1", Column2 = str + "2"... matches to strings in JS code ( { "mDataProp": "Column1" } ...). I can generate n JS lines for n columns like this: @{for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {"mDataProp" : "Column" + @i } }. But I can't "generate" the C# code in similar way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problems. Generating JavaScript is easier that I thought. The problem was that when I generated the aoColumns array as the C# string and then assigned it to "aoColumns" property like this:

```
"aoColumns": [
    @propertyStr
],
```

the compiler somehow hid the quotes and braces.
The right way was to do this:

```
"aoColumns": [
    @Html.Raw(propertyStr)
],
```

Answer (score 1):

DataTables does not allow to change column dynamically but you can get columns before data and   load datatable on its callback function...

```
$.ajax('url/columns', function(data){

   //write table header

var options =   
"bProcessing": true, 
"bServerSide": true, 
"sAjaxSource": getGridDataUrl, 
"iDisplayLength": 10,
"aoColumns": //column settingssss
};
    $('#myDataTable').dataTable(options);

});
```

Comment: Please look at the "Added" section of my question, I would appreciate any help)

Comment: You didt mention the exact problem but letme explain you dattable require table header and setting before columns so write table header & columns setting before calling data.  You can get complete column setting string from server and use "aoCoulmns": eval( @columnsettings)